# How To Use Clear Rect Function For Movement In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a game using pure javascript and the clearRect function isn't working correctly, here's the code:

```
//player's location
var playerX = 250;
var playerY = 325;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'w' && playerY >= borderW && movement === true) {
    playerY -= playerSpeed;
    //Clears the head of the Protagonist
    ctx.clearRect(playerX + 2.5, playerY + 2.5, 20, 20);
    //Clears the body of the protagonist
    ctx.clearRect(playerX + 5, playerY + 17.5, 15, 25);
    drawProtagonistFacingUp();
  }
  if (e.key == 'd' && playerX < borderD && movement === true) {
    playerX += playerSpeed;
    ctx.clearRect(playerX, playerY, -200, 200);
    drawProtagonistFacingRight();
  }
  if (e.key == 's' && playerY < borderS && movement === true) {
    playerY += playerSpeed;
    ctx.clearRect(playerX, playerY - 15, 200, 200);
    drawProtagonistFacingDown();
  }
  if (e.key == 'a' && playerX > borderA && movement === true) {
    playerX -= playerSpeed;
    ctx.clearRect(playerX, playerY, 200, 200);
    drawProtagonistFacingLeft();
  }
});
```

What's supposed to happen is when the player presses w, a, s, or d to move, it'll clear the old player image off of the screen and draw a new one. However, what it is doing now is clearing only a small amount of the player image. If possible, a simple solution would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you `playerX + 2.5`? For all intents and purposes, pixels only exist at integer positions, not floating point positions.

Comment: @MikeC, what do yu mean, I'm really sorry if I'm just being silly. I'm a very amateur developer so my knowledge of javascript isn't the best

Comment: What are the dimensions of the player?

Comment: @mm759, whoops, i forgot to add that, I'll edit it now

Comment: @Meeeeee What I mean is that you're only going to have pixels at `0, 0`, `100, 325`, etc. Not `1.5, 2.2`, `100.4, 325.5`, etc.

Comment: Do you use browser zoom (only a guess that this could influence the results)?

Comment: @mm759 no, i don't, i use Google Chrome

Comment: @Meeeeee Could you please create an example (perhaps use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to get it working) that shows your problem? You can use services like [Placehold.it](http://placehold.it/) to render images in any size.

Comment: The way you animate with the canvas is set up a main animation loop function that is called by `requestAnimationFrame(mainLoopFuntion)` In that function you first clear the whole canvas, or draw the background image over the top of the last frame. Then you render the game objects from back to front in order of visibility. That way you dont have to worry about clearing past positions, what to do when there is overlap, and so on...

Comment: @Blindman67 thanks! Mind putting that as an answer so i could check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Clear the canvas.

The way you animate with the canvas is set up a main animation loop function that is called by `requestAnimationFrame`

```
function update(time){ // requestAnimationFrame calls this function with the 
                       // argument time. Time is in ms (1/1000th second) but
                       // accurate to 1/1,000,000th second,  0.001ms

    ... your code
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // request the next frame
}
requestAnimationFrame(update); // start the animation
```

Under standard setups browsers will call the function 60 times a second.

Rather than keep track of each object and clearing it then re rendering it it is much simpler to clear the whole canvas. This can be done a few ways

```
function update(time){ 
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height); // Make all pixels
                                                           // transparent
    // or
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"; // can use solid colour, gradient, or pattern
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
    // or 
    // use a background image
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
    ... your code
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // request the next frame
}
requestAnimationFrame(update); // start the animation
```

Once the canvas is clear you can then render you objects in order, where the last object will appear over object drawn befor. This approch greatly simplifies your animation code.